# My menu is broken in Magento and the browser says js file is disabled

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have Magento 1.9.3.1 installed on my site. Recently I have hired a person to work on the site's speed optimization issue. But he has done something wrong and now my menu and the footer disappeared suddenly. I checked everything. Checked the blocks from **CMS>Static Blocks**. Then also checked the theme settings, enabled template path hints and checked my **head.phtml**, **index.phtml**..Everything seems fine. The theme settings as well as the template files are ok but the menu is missing. After that I ran my site through a proxy site and then I can see the menu appeared there but the menu seemed broken and it shows **JavaScript seems to be disabled in your browser**. I have attached the screenshot below. I have also cleared the cache from the admin panel as well as from **var>cache** folder. I have no idea how to overcome that. Can anyone please help?
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors in browser's console?

Comment: Nope. When I visit it from my browser, I don't get any error. But when I check from the proxy site, I get 13 uncaught error.

Comment: Could you please share URL of website?

Comment: Sure. Here's the url: http://www.nakarjewelry.com/ . Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I can see both Menu and footer are displaying. http://prnt.sc/dsnqdm . http://prnt.sc/dsnqn2 . Only the social icons in footer are missing. http://www.nakarjewelry.com/skin/frontend/smartwave/porto/images/social-icons-sprite.png http://www.nakarjewelry.com/skin/frontend/smartwave/porto/images/social-icons-hover-sprite.png

Comment: I don't know what's the issue but from my browser, I can't see the menu neither the footer. It's only visible when I visit it via a proxy network:
http://prnt.sc/dsntxy

Comment: Try removing your browser's cache or press ctrl + f5.

Comment: Problem solved. Some custom code was doing that. I just removed them.